# Error in corrplot.mixed in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to display correlation plot using corrplot.mixed() for all numeric variables. But the plot is not getting displayed.

Please check my code

ui

```
                  fluidRow(
                    box(title = "Correlation Plot", width = 12, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary", 
                        collapsible = TRUE, plotOutput("plot3")))
```

Server

```
  dataset_1 <- reactive({
    switch(input$Datasets,
           "Train" = Train(),
           "Test" = Test())
  }) 

 output$plot3 <- renderPlot({

   is.num <- sapply(dataset_1(), is.integer)
   df1 <- dataset_1()[, is.num]

   corrplot.mixed(df1, is.corr = FALSE)
   })
```

Please find the error,

Warning: Error in matrix: length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

Comment: Please post your complete code if this is possible.

Comment: My complete code is more than 300 lines, so i was not able to post complete code. But i have posted the relevant code here.

Comment: Try `is.numeric` instead of `is.integer`

Comment: I think that `is.corr` is not an argument of `corrplot.mixed`. Try `corrplot.mixed(cor(df1))` instead of `corrplot.mixed(df1, is.corr = F)`

Comment: when i try, corrplot.mixed(cor(df1)). I get this error Error in symbols: invalid symbol coordinates